# Java Type Inference Error

Tags: java, lambda, types, functional-programming

I was playing with using functions to represent pairs. I had `Pair<A>` version working which has two elements with the same type. I went on and worked on a pair of `A, B`. When I compiled the following code, I got the error message below:

```
fp2.java:34: error: method pairing in class fp cannot be applied to given types;
    return fp.<A,B>pairing().apply(a).apply(b);
             ^
  required: no arguments
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

I am pretty sure there is some problem with error message (required and found). Not sure if `javac` is rejecting correct solution or not. Most likely that's my problem. Can someone help me fix this error? Or refine the design (so that a pair of `A, B` can work).

```
public class fp2 {

  interface First<A,B> {
    Function<B,A> apply(A a);
  }

  interface Second<A,B> {
    Function<B,B> apply(A a);
  }

  interface Pair<A,B> {
     A apply(First<A,B> fst);
     B apply(Second<A,B> fst);
  }

  interface I2<A,B> {
    Pair<A,B> apply(B b);
  }

public static <A,B> I3<A,B> pairing() {
    return a -> b -> new Pair<A,B> () {
      public A apply(First<A,B> fst) { return fst.apply(a).apply(b); }
      public B apply(Second<A,B> snd) { return snd.apply(a).apply(b); }
    };
  }

  public static <A,B> Pair<A,B> pair(A a, B b) {
    return fp.<A,B>pairing().apply(a).apply(b);
  }

  public static <A,B> First<A,B> fst() {
    return a1 -> a2 -> a1;
  }

  public static <A,B> Second<A,B> snd() {
    return a1 -> a2 -> a2;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pair<Integer,Double> p1 = pair(1,2.0);
    System.out.println(p1.apply(fst()));
    System.out.println(p1.apply(snd()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to shrinkdown your code to an absolute minimum. Does the error message stay, if you remove `apply()`?

Comment: What's `fp`?  I don't see it defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: @JacobG. What a lesson! `fp` is the one that deals with a pair of `A,A`, defined in another file. That's the fix!